# Loop while variable is not an integer

Tags: python, while-loop, int

Hullo hullo! 
I'm working on a program that calculates the input scores and outputs the grade percentage and a letter grade. While the letter grading part is super simple, I'm having trouble getting the while loop done right.
Currently, I'm trying to add an input trap by making the user only input whole numbers between 0 and 10. The problem is, whenever the user DOES enter the necessary input, it ends up looping and returning the output `"Please enter a whole number." continuously

```
print ( "Enter the homework scores one at a time. Type \"done\" when finished." )
hwCount = 1 
strScore = input ( "HW#" + str ( hwCount ) + " score: " ) 
while ( strScore != int and strScore != "done" )  or\
      ( strScore == int and ( strScore < 0 or strScore >10 )):
         if strScore == int:
            input = int ( input ( "Please enter a number between 0 and 10." ))
         else:
         print ( "Please enter only whole numbers." )
        #End if
         strScore = float ( input ( "enter HW#" + str( hwCount ) + " score:
```

So, I'll probably feel pretty dumb once I figure this out, but I'm stumped. The algorithmic solution states 
Loop while ( strScore is not an integer and strScore !="done") or 
           ( strScore is an integer and (strScore < 0 or strScore > 10)))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You definitely should check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

Comment: 1) `input` value is always a string.
2) use `type(strScore)` if you want to compare types.

Answer (score 1):

`strScore != int` doesn't test if the value is an integer; it checks if the value equal to the `int` type. You want `not isinstance(strScore, int)` in this case.

However, you should try to avoid making direct type checks. The important thing is that a value *behaves* like an float.

```
print("Enter the homework scores one at a time. Type \"done\" when finished.")
hwCount = 1 
while True:
    strScore = input("HW#{} score: ".format(hwCount))
    if strScore == "done":
        break
    try:
        score = float(strScore)
    except ValueError:
        print("{} is not a valid score, please try again".format(strScore))
        continue

    if not (0 <= score <= 10):
        print("Please enter a value between 1 and 10")
        continue

    # Work with the validated value of score
    # ...
    hwCount += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this! Is there a way I could write this that does not use the While True format?

Comment: That's a common Python idiom. It's often cleaner to assume a loop is infinite, breaking when appropriate, than it is to try to fit all the logic in the exit condition. It also helps when you have code (like `input("HW#1 score: ")`) that is supposed to execute *at least* once, guaranteeing that you will enter the loop.